# Replace every nth character with "-" in java without regex

Tags: java

I am trying to replace every nth character in a string with some special character for e.g "`-`" so based on value of input (`int n` and `String str`), I want to replace all chars at `n` ( like `2`, `4`, `6`) by this special characters so the length of string is maintained and this is what I have so far but it is not yielding correct output.

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
      String result="";
      for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i+=n){
            result += " " + str.charAt(i);  
      } 
      return result;
}
```

Comment: Where in that code are you replacing something?

Comment: The modulus (`%`) operator is going to be your best friend here.

Comment: Your code should be working...why don't u think it is producing the correct results? Input:`test`,`2` results in: t s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) that will be initialized with your input `String`, then use [`setCharAt(int index, char ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt-int-char-) to modify a given char, this way you avoid building a new `String` at each iteration as you currently do with the operator `+=` on `String`.

Something like:

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
    if (n < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be greater than 0");
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str);
    // This will replace every nth character with '-'
    for (int i = n - 1; i < str.length(); i += n) {
        result.setCharAt(i, '-');
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

**NB:** Starts from `n - 1` unless you want to replace the first character too if so starts from `0`.

---

If you want to simply remove the characters, you should use the method [`append(CharSequence s, int start, int end)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.CharSequence-int-int-) to build the content of your target `String`, as next:

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
    if (n < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be greater than 0");
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    // The index of the previous match
    int previous = 0;
    for (int i = n-1; i < str.length(); i += n) {
        // Add substring from previous match to the current
        result.append(str, previous, i);
        // Set the new value of previous
        previous = i + 1;
    }
    // Add the remaining sub string
    result.append(str, previous, str.length());
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. This is probably the most efficient way to do the task (as stringbuilders are way more efficient than concatenating multiple strings)

Comment: you might want to let the loop start at `i=n-1` (unless you want to start replacing at the first char)

Comment: how do I remove those characters at index?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't replace in a Java String. They're immutable. So you're going to have to make a new String with the right properties. There are a number of ways to do this, one of which involves iterating over the original String and copying characters unless the current index is a multiple of n. 
You could also convert the String to an Array and loop over every nth element of the array and change those.

Comment: -1. Please read the code that I have provided. I am creating another new String   to hold the results as I am aware of the fact that Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus operator (`%`) to achieve what you are trying to like so:

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0,n=str.length;i<n;i++){
        if(i%n==0){
            sb.append("-");
        else{
            sb.append(str.charAt(i);
        }
     }
     return sb.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use modulus, it could go like this:

```
public static String everyNth(String str, int n, char append) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (i % n == 0) {
            sb.append(append);
        } else {
            sb.append(str.charAt(i-1));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```