# Remove/Delete every Nth character from string

Tags: java, android

I used Android Studio to make a simple app.

Example:

n=3, then i should delete every third char(it's not a const but from an input)

**I LOVE STACKOVERFLOW** -----> **I OV SACOVRFOW**

I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/41813029 method, because the topic is similar (when other is not).

```
buttonprocess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String s = edittextkata.getText().toString();
        String kunci = editkey.getText().toString();

        if (s.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CAN NOT ENCRYPT! Plaintext is empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (kunci.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CAN NOT ENCRYPT! KEY is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            int k = Integer.parseInt(editkey.getText().toString());
            String str = edittextkata.getText().toString();

            if (k < 1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("k must be greater than 0");
            }
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            int previous = 0;
            for (int i = k - 1; i < str.length(); i += k) {
                result.append(str, previous, i);
                previous = i + 1;
            }
            result.append(str, previous, str.length());
            return result.toString();

            //Show the result to edittext
            edittexthasil.setText(result);
        }
```

But his code is error

Error:(66, 43) error: incompatible types: unexpected return value

Actually the output should be

I OV SACOVRFOW&LETKEL

But, my idk how. And i have deadline *cry. Help!

nb:pardon my grammar.

Comment: You can't return a value from a `void` method.

Comment: What do you believe `return result.toString()` is doing, and why do you believe so? Consider this: 1) Method is declared to return `void`, so what is being returned? 2) `return` statement is followed by a `edittexthasil.setText(result)` statement. How would that ever execute with the `return` statement there? --- Remove the `return` statement.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so much. Now that i think over it. . .I should check it more carefully before copasting from other code. And i'm sorry, i'm a newbie to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
return result.toString();

//Show the result to edittext
edittexthasil.setText(result);
```

with:

```
//Show the result to edittext
edittexthasil.setText(result.toString());
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted if it helped you, Thanks.